# How to read a value from Firebase realtime database with a Google cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm starting to use firebase cloud functions, and I have trouble reading an entry **"Hello"** from my database tree :

[image]

I'm trying to read the **"Hello"** value inside **HANDLE/suj1/part1** from my tree. I am using a firebase cloud function that is triggered when I create an other entry with an IOS Application in the database inside **"INTENT"**. The functions gets called well but every time I try to read the "Hello" value , it returns a null value in my firebase console where I expect it to return "Hello".

Here is the code I use :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.match = functions.database.ref('INTENT/{userid}').onCreate(snapshot => {

const user = snapshot.key


return admin.database().ref('HANDLE/suj1/part1').once('value', (snap) => {
    const hello = snap.val()
    console.log(hello) // Null
 });
```

Can someone tell what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Just to see what your database looks like, can you try this and add its output to your question? `return admin.database().ref().once('value', (snap) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(snap.val()));
 });`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, I try what you said, I found out there was a space a the end of HANDLE, I could have not seen it from the console. You guys  should think to add a way to modify a node from the console because now once a node is created you can't modify it's name. Thanks again !

Comment: Great to hear that you found the cause of the problem Mathias! Renaming nodes has never been much requested, but it never hurts to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out with this line and Frank's help:

```
admin.database().ref().once('value', (snap) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(snap.val())); });
```

That I had added a whitespace at the end of "HANDLE " in my path, which does not appear in the Firebase console. I had to delete the branch and create an other one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.match = 
functions.database.ref('OTHERLOCATION/{userid}').onCreate((snapshot) => {
const user = snapshot.key

return admin.database().ref().child('HANDLE/suj1').once('value', function(snap) => {
const hello = snap.val().part1
console.log(hello) // "Hello"
});
```

Comment: I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'part1' of null

Comment: edit your question with a screnshot of your firebase database node.. If it's as you said into your question, it should work :S

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
const userName = admin.database().ref('/HANDLE/suj1/part1').once('value',function(snapshot) {

const hello = snapshot.val();
console.log(hello);

});
```